# Lambda with multiple parameters in find_if

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, lambda, find

I've got a vector with objects of a custom data type. One of the fields of this data type is an enum. I want to make sure that for all enum values at least one entry is added to the vector.

I want to use `std::find_if()` to check if the vector has an entry for a certain enum value. But I'm not sure how to write & use the lambda correctly. Here's what I got:

```
struct CustomType
{
  EnumType type {EnumType::DEFAULT};
  int x;
};

std::vector<CustomType> tmp;

// fetch values from database and add them to the vector
// for some EnumType values there might not be a record added to the vector

auto hasEnumType = [](const CustomType& customType, const EnumType& enumType) -> bool
{
  return (customType.type == enumType);
};

// What do I replace '?' with to get the current position
if (std::find_if(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), hasEnumType(?, EnumType::VALUE1)) != tmp.end())
{
  //add CustomType with VALUE1 to vector
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check against a fixed value, you can simply put it inside the lambda.

```
if ( std::find_if(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), [](CustomType const & customType)
                  { return customType.type == EnumType::VALUE; }) )
{ /* do something */}
```

If you want, in a sense, pass it to lambda as parameter, you can set it in an external variable and "capture" it by reference

```
auto enumType = EnumType::VALUE;

// capture variables by references --------V
if ( std::find_if(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), [&](CustomType const & customType)
                  { return customType.type == enumType; }) )
{ /* do something */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::find_if` takes a unary predicate as its third parameter. If you provide binary predicate it will fail type check.

One way to do this is to convert your binary predicate to unary predicate by capturing one of its parameters. To automate it for all `enum` values create a function that returns another function.

```
auto getTypeChecker = [](const EnumType enumType)
{
    return [enumType](const CustomType& customType)
    {
        return (customType.type == enumType);
    };
};
```

then declare a function that takes care of inserting enum values that are not present in the vector -

```
void insert_if_not_present(std::vector<CustomType>& vec, const EnumType type)
{
    if(std::none_of(begin(vec), end(vec), getTypeChecker(type)))
    {
        //add CustomType with type to vec
    }
}
```

Now call `insert_if_not_present` once for each enum value.

**Note**, here I have used `std::none_of` for convenience. You can use `std::find_if` in place of `std::none_of` in smae manner.